# Are these two 2-manifolds homeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

I have a 2-Sphere with a finite number $k$ of points removed (at least 3), and I want to equip it with a Riemannian metric of constant negative curvature.

My first thought was to take a free subgroup $A_k$ of rank $k$ of the isometries of the hyperbolic plane $H$, which acts fix point free and discontinuous on $H$ (such a group exists).

If I take the quotient $H/A_k$, I end up with a complete manifold of constant negative curvature, with isomorphic fundamental group to the punctured Sphere, but are those two manifolds homeomorphic? Maybe this is a terribly clumsy way to try to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not necessarily the case.

Take the sphere with 3 punctures: it has fundamental group free on two generators, right?

Now take the torus with one puncture (which has indeed a hyperbolic structure). You can easily see this has the same fundamental group.
So, to answer your question you probably need to know which group you are using (simply because we have just seen that it depends on that).

To endow the thrice punctured sphere with a hyperbolic metric, you should start with two identical copies of an ideal triangle in $\mathbb{H}^2$, and glue them together. If you are careful you can check that this gives you a hyperbolic surface homeomorphic to $S^2-\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$.
Do you see how you could generalize this to, say, a 4-punctured sphere?

For another approach, non explicit:
A thrice punctured sphere $S$ can be embedded (continuously) in $\mathbb{C}$, as $\mathbb{C}$ with two holes. So, $S$ has a riemann surface structure. By the riemann mapping theorem, it is holomorphically covered by $\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane (since we removed at least 2 points). This allows you to put a hyperbolic metric on $S$. For details and references, check the wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem#Geometric_classification_of_surfaces

Comment: Ah, right, thanks! I didn't think it through there. Still I want to try to avoid any explicit construction of this punctured sphere in hyperbolic space if possible. Could there be a way to use the uniformization theorem? If I can rule out the possibility for the punct. sphere to be a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by a nice group of euclidean isometries, then there has to be a metric of constant negative curvature on this sphere (the positive curvature case is ruled out because the fundamental group is not finite). Maybe it's not possible to find such a "nice" free subgroup of eucl. isometries?

Comment: Well, do you just need to show that it exists, or do you need to find one?

Comment: Also, I'd like to "nudge" you towards an explicit construction. This has the advantage that you realize how many different hyperbolic structures you can endow it with, and also makes you realize what makes them distinct.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, but for now it would suffice for me to know, that there exists one. The only way I can think of doing this, is by showing that there is no free subgroup (of rank at least 2) of the isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which acts freely and properly discontinuous. I don't really know if this makes sense.

Comment: Well, it's easy to see that the euclidean isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are just traslations and rotations, and that any subgroup acting freely and discretely must be either trivial, infinite cyclic generated by a traslation, or $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by two independent traslations.
I added a bit at the end of the answer, concerning the use of the mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are saying the same thing but in a slightly different order. Isn't it true that a sphere with at least 3 points removed is homeomorphic to an open set in a compact Riemann surface of genus $\geq2$?

If so, the latter can be endowed with a constant negative curvature because it is uniformized by the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: I think it is implied that riemannian metric of constant negative curvature means that it is complete.